# Creating a hierarchy in Mondrian/Saiku with names from different tables

Tags: mondrian, saiku

Let's say we've got a fact table "bi_slots", in which there are fields (id,region_id,city_id). In fact there are more fields, but they are of no interest here.

There also is 'regions' table in which there are (id,name) fields and 'cities' table with (id,name,region_id) fields.

What i need is to make a Dimension for a Cube of "bi_slots" where applied is Region->Сity hierarchy. And, i would need to grab region and city name from their respective tables.

So, Dimension looks like:

```
<Dimension name="AddressDimension" caption="Address">
    <Hierarchy name="AddressHierarchy" hasAll="true" primaryKey="id" caption="Region" allMemberCaption="Regions">
      <Table name="regions"/>  
      <Level table="regions" column="id" nameColumn="name" name="RegionLevel" uniqueMembers="true" type="String" caption="Region"/>
      <Level table="cities" column="id" nameColumn="name" name="CityLevel" uniqueMembers="true" type="String" caption="City"/>      
    </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>
```

And the declaration for the Cube with this dimensionUsage

```
<Cube name="SlotsCube" caption="Slot Cube">
   <View alias="bi_slots">
     <SQL><![CDATA[
       select *, date_trunc('day', created_at) as date_created_at from bi_slots
     ]]></SQL>
   </View>

<DimensionUsage name="AddressDimension" source="AddressDimension" foreignKey="region_id"/>
```

Being put like this, it makes Mondrian not show this cube at all, but when i delete CityLevel from my dimension i get a perfectly fine filtering by regions.

Any help would be more than welcome, we are really out of ideas here.

Comment: What you want to achieve with SQL in Cube View? I used it maybe twice when there was a very complex data? You can really simplify things moving from snowflake to star schema? In ETL process make table Address (ID, City_Name, ID_Region, Region_Name). Put Region as top level. Saiku is not showing cube when something is wrong in cube settings, you can check out log file, or try modifying xml in Pentaho Schema Workbench.

Comment: SQL in view is insignificant, a simple transformation for another dimension which only cares about the day of creation, not Date&time. So the very best practice is to create a helper table?

Comment: Snowflake is useful in few cases: When you can't construct StarSchema, when there is a meny:many relationship, when your dimensions are high cardinality. In your case, it's best to read log file and check this: http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php#Star_schemas

Comment: Thanks! Star schema it is then.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot add columns from different tables just like that.

First, and as pointed out in the comments to the post, you should use a star schema.

But, if you can't or don't want to, you can create the join, specifying the various tables involved and how to join. Only after defining it you can reference columns in different tables in the same dimension.

See chapter 4 of the [documentation](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php).